# Why does Neo4j APOC Cypher export ignore unwindBatchSize command?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm using the Neo4j (3.5.1) apoc-3.5.0.4 plugin for exporting a subgraph of a Neo4j DB.

Within the Cypher exports I always have a large block of UNWIND nodes (> 500).

As I understand the documentation at https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/export-import/#export-cypher the default limit for the batch size "portions" is 100. My export creates much larger UNWIND blocks.

When trying to import the exported Cypher file via the Cypher Shell the import exactly stops at the first large block of UNWINDs with the following error:

Invalid input '{': expected an identifier character, whitespace, FROM GRAPH, CONSTRUCT, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE UNIQUE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, CALL, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 2, column 2593 (offset: 2593))

The mentioned documentation says that the batch size can be controlled by the

```
useOptimizations:{unwindBatchSize: 10}
```

parameter to limit the amount of UNWIND entries.

But when I set it to a smaller value (e.g. 10) to force the export to limit the UNWIND size of entries it works fine up to a random point within the export. Without any recognizable cause after a random amount of lines the export starts building large blocks of bundled nodes (up 1000 nodes).

I use the following command to export the subgraph from the Neo4j DB:

```
MATCH (a:LABEL1)-[r:LINK]->(b:LABEL1)
WHERE a.title IN [xyz,...]
WITH collect(a)+collect(b) as export_nodes, collect(r) as export_rels
CALL apoc.export.cypher.data(export_nodes,export_rels,"export.cypher",
{format:'plain',cypherFormat:'updateAll', useOptimizations:
{type:'unwind_batch',unwindBatchSize: 10}}) 
YIELD file, source, format, nodes, relationships, properties, time
RETURN nodes, relationships, time;
```

I'm using the following command to import the Cypher File:

```
$NEO4J_HOME/bin/cypher-shell -u myuser -p mypassword < 'export.cypher'
```

The import works fine till the error. All the nodes within the Cypher file - up to the point where the error occurs - are imported correctly.

I played around with the unwindBatchSize command a bit to check if it - at least up to a certain point - works correct. So I checked a 5 nodes UNWIND limit as well. This creates well formed blocks of 5 entries up to row 200..500 when suddenly a huge block appears.

Does anyone has a tip how to correct this behavior?

Many thanks in advance

Krid

---

### UPDATE

While creating an anonymized excerpt of the generated Cypher output I recognized that probably not the unwindBatchSize is the main cause of the problem. Looking at the data in more detail I found that the line breaks and the missing Cypher command MERGE appear to be the cause of the error.

When you look at the index position 9:605 and 9:1142 (of the provided export below) you see that there should be a line break and the MERGE command entry. Instead of this the output continues with the content.

I haven't changed any structure of the output (just anonymized the labels, properties and content).

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (node:Entity) ASSERT (node.title) IS UNIQUE;
UNWIND [{title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}},  {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:1, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}] as row
MERGE (n:Entity{title: row.title}) SET n += row.properties;
UNWIND [{title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}] as row
MERGE (n:Entity{title: row.title}) SET n += row.properties;
...
<for the next 200 blocks everything works as expacted... when suddenly the MERGE line is no longer generated>
...
UNWIND [{title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:1, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:1, prop2:0, prop3:0}}] as row{title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:1, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:1, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}] as row{title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0, ...
...
<This behaviour repeats for a while an suddenly it falls back to the expacted blocks set by the unwindBatchSize>
...
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (node:Entity) ASSERT (node.title) IS UNIQUE;
UNWIND [{title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:1, prop2:0, prop3:0}}, {title:"Xyz_Xyz", properties:{prop1:0, prop2:0, prop3:0}}] as row
MERGE (n:Entity{title: row.title}) SET n += row.properties;
...
<The exported structure for adding the relations appear to be ok>
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for spotting this. Can you please provide a sample dataset in order to reproduce it?

Comment: Hello Michael, thanks for reaching out. Unfortunately I can't provide the dataset because it is GDPR relevant and the size of the whole Neo4j DB is currently over 30GB. That's one of the reasons we need a way to slice it down into smaller chunks for individual analysis. But I can share the general schema structure of the DB. It is actually pretty simple:

Comment: (Entity)-[LINKS_TO]->(Entity) and (Entity)-[BELONGS_TO]->(Entity_Class)

Currently the whole DB consists of approx. half a billion relations. I will post an anonymized export created with the APOC Cypher procedure within my question as update

Comment: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/1209#issuecomment-505515694